# Event handler for a dynamically added button

Tags: c#, event-handling

Code :

```
 public partial class Form3 : Form
 {
    ...
    ...
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        TextBox diaryName = new TextBox();
        Button b = new Button();
        Label l = new Label();

        diaryName.Font = new Font("Consolas", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
        b.Font = buttonFont;
        l.Font = buttonFont;
        b.BackColor = Color.Wheat;

        l.Text = "Diary Name : ";
        b.Text = "Add Diary";
        Point lbl = l.Location;
        diaryName.Location = new Point(l.Location.X + l.Width + 5, lbl.Y);
        Point txtbox = diaryName.Location;
        b.Location = new Point(txtbox.X + diaryName.Width + 20, txtbox.Y);
        p.Controls.Add(l);
        p.Controls.Add(diaryName);
        p.Controls.Add(b);
        p.Location = new Point(12,272);
        p.Size = new Size(20 + 20 + 20 + diaryName.Width + l.Width + b.Width, diaryName.Height);
        // I need help here..
        // b.Click += new EventHandler(); ???
        this.Controls.Add(p);
        this.Height += 50;
        this.Width += 30;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;

    }
    ...
  }
```

The above code adds a panel that contains a label,a textBox and a button to the form , that's all working fine, my problem is that I want to handle click event of the dynamically added button (b) , In my event handling code I should be able to access the dynamically added TextBox (**diaryName**) for validation purposes, but I don't know how to do It. I tried adding another function within the same class Form3 , but since The textbox t is created within the button1_Click function, I am unable to access the textbox , so How can I get around this ?

I am new to c#, I have a Java background so is there any way in c# to declare event handlers like this

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("You clicked the button");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy assign a handler to the button's event this way:

```
b.Click += new EventHandler(newButtonClick);
```

where

```
protected void newButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Access your textbox like this
    var myTextBox = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(tb=>tb.Name == "diaryName");
    if(myTextBox!=null)
    {
        //rest of your code here
    }
}
```

However it's a poor practice. Your button will depend heavily on the objects created dynamically somewhere outside - that breaks encapsulation rule of OOP. Secondly - did you think what will happen if you'll click your original button (the one you showed your handler for) twice?

edit: When I've come to think about it, your method is not that dynamic really. It creates those controls on the fly, but they're not generic in any way - it's a static piece of code, that creates always the same result. So in this case I'd think about putting your new panel, textbox and button in the form as a public items and then initialize them inside your method.
It'd be even better to create them in the visual studio's designer already, hide them using `Visible` properties and then in `button1_Click` you could only change their sizes and show them up.

Comment: +1 for _did you think what will happen if you'll click your original button (the one you showed your handler for) twice?_

Answer (score 0):

Ok, need to add event for button click,

1) So after you create new Button

```
          Button b = new Button();
```

2) next add click event for that

```
          b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
```

3) and then write the actual function body for click event in your code

```
           void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
               {
                  //Your code for click operation
               }
```

Comment: where should the b_Click be ? within the button1_Click or in the form3 class as a separate function?

Comment: but If it is after `button1_Click` How can I access the `diaryName` textBox which is inside `button1_Click` ??

Comment: in that case you have to make TextBox diaryName public, and then use diaryName = new TextBox(); in button1_click